# Link for most recent version of Font Awesome?

Tags: hyperlink, cdn, font-awesome

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a link/CDN that always points to the most recent, latest version of Font Awesome. I hate having to go back to my sites and update the version number for my CDN include each time.

Thanks!
- Mickey

Comment: What's wrong with hosting it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some discussion of this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/stack_developers/n6TSGRzjp8E

Answer (score 0):

It is better to host fontawesome locally than referring to cdn. One more thing I would like to tell you is, you can't change the fontawesome version 3.x.x to 4.x.x because there are major class and icon name changes exists. If you are using 3.x.x, then i suggest you not to change the version by simply replacing the files. if wish to change, you have to replace the class names everywhere in your website.